# How do I stop elements from 'submerging' under the screen when changing window's size in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a box on second half of the page, but the problem is that whenever I resize the viewport (Doesn't matter if it's height or width) it just goes under the screen ignoring the bottom margin :(

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url('bg.png');
  background-size: contain;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.section1,
.section2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.section2 {
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  margin-right: 3%;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 90vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section1">
      <div id="MainBox">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" id="ImageHouse">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section2">
    </div>
</body>
```

Here's the visualization of what I mean:

[image]

I tried playing around with different width, height and it's max values but with no results :(

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set it on your container that the children shouldn't wrap:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  gap: 1vw;
}

.item {
  background-color: silver;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
</div>
```